# file.read() of png file bug?

Tags: python, file, png

I'm trying read a PNG image in pure text, as in the notepad. (For later conversion to base64).

test images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNhX3.png

So I tried this code:

```
f = 'test1.png'
with open(f) as file:
    for i in xrange(0, 5):
        print(i, f, file.read())
print
f = 'test2.png'
with open(f) as file:
    for i in xrange(0, 5):
        print(i, f, file.read())
```

But it not read the entire file, such as "read" function is suppose to do.
If I try call `read` again for some PNGs it read one more part, for others it didn't, no matter how often called.

I only have this output:

```
(0, 'test1.png', '\x89PNG\n')
(1, 'test1.png', '')
(2, 'test1.png', '')
(3, 'test1.png', '')
(4, 'test1.png', '')

(0, 'test2.png', '\x89PNG\n')
(1, 'test2.png', '\xd2y\xb4j|\x8f\x0b5MW\x98D\x97\xfc\x13\\7\x11\xcaPn\x18\x80,}\xc6g\x90\xc5n\x8cDi\x81\xf9\xbel\xd6Fl\x11\xae\xdf s\xf0')
(2, 'test2.png', '')
(3, 'test2.png', '')
(4, 'test2.png', '')
```

But I want it like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvuvj.png

It's a bug?

Any other (simple) way to get this file in base64?

Comment: Have you tried `open(f, 'rb')`?

Comment: Thx, @TigerhawkT3. It's work with this flags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG files are not text files; you must read them as binary files, not text files, like so:

```
with open(f, 'rb') as file:
```

If you want to produce the base64 encoding of the data, use the `base64` module:

```
import base64
f = 'test1.png'
with open(f) as file:
    for i in xrange(0, 5):
        print(i, f, base64.b64encode(file.read()))
```